# In JPA select purchase orders that do not have an associated sale contract

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I have a data model with 2 tables:

- purchaseorder
- salecontract

The associated `SaleContract` Java class contains a field `PurchaseOrder` po. There is a one to one relationship between `PurchaseOrder` and `SaleContract`. The `PurchaseOrder` class (and table) is not aware of the `SaleContract` class (which contains the field and the foreign key).

I want to select all those purchase orders that *do not* have an associated sale contract. I can't quite get my head around this one.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
@Entity
public class SaleContract {

@Id
private String identifier;
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.DETACH)
private PurchaseOrder po;
private double amount;
private String customerName;
private String salesRepresentative;
```

And

```
@Entity
public class PurchaseOrder {

@Id
private String identifier;
private double amount;
private String purchaser;
private String location;
private boolean approved;
```

Comment: Show us entity classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's quite counterintuitive - you need to use `right join` as follows:

```
select po from SaleContact sc right join sc.po po where sc is null
```

Comment: Also Select from PurchaseOrder po where po.id NOT IN (select scpo.id from SaleContract sc JOIN sc.purchaseOrder scpo)

Comment: Thanks! Is this JPA-compliant or this already entering SQL specifics?